# How to properly link two object files without affecting rip relative addressing?

Tags: assembly, rust, linker, ld, instructions

I have two object files, one is generated from assembly and another is compiled from rust. From the assembly I call a function in the rust (as below) so I need to link them together.

```
//boot.asm
section .text
...
extern _start
call _start
...

//main.rs
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn _start() {
    let hello = b"hello_world!";
    ...
}
```

After compile I found there are a `.rodata` section and a `.text` section in the rust object file, and there are instructions that use rip-relative addressing to address the "hello world" string in the `.rodata` section:

```
//section .text
...
  let hello = b"hello world!";
2017e7: 48 8d 05 2e ea ff ff    lea    -0x15d2(%rip),%rax
2017ee: 48 89 44 24 30          mov    %rax,0x30(%rsp)
...
```

I also have `.rodata` section and `.text` section in the assembly. However, during linking the linker just merge the two `.rodata` sections and two `.text` sections into one `.rodata` section and one `.text` section, which affects the rip-relative addressing, causing my program not working working.
Can anybody tell me how should I make modifications to resolve the problem?
This is my linker script, Should I modify it?

```
ENTRY(start)

SECTIONS {
    . = 0x00100000;

    .boot :
    {
        *(.multiboot_header)
    }

    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `.o` object files have relocation metadata which gets resolved at link time.  The RIP-relative offset isn't even calculated until link time; in the `.o` it's normally just a `00 00 00 00` placeholder for the rel32 to be filled in at link time (based on the target symbol).  Disassemble the `.o` with `objdump -drwC` to show relocation.

Comment: TL:DR: this part should Just Work; whatever problem you're having probably isn't caused by this.  Does your linker script need an entry for the `.rodata` section and also `.data` and/or `.bss`?

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I was following a [tutorial](https://os.phil-opp.com/multiboot-kernel/#building-the-executable) of building OS from scratch. As for the previous problem, I compiled the rust and assembly separately and linked them manully. The rust doesn't know it is going to be linked with another object so I think it would not leave a placeholder there in this case. I checked that instruction in the object and it remians the same before and after linking. You can check my [repo](https://github.com/Stuart0l/Small-OS-in-Rust/tree/dev) to see if other thing cause the bug. Thanks.

Comment: Compiler back-ends like LLVM *always* use relocation entries even for references to labels defined in the same compilation unit, unless it's within the same *section*.  e.g. for jump targets.  I haven't looked at Rust compiler output specifically, but it's the same LLVM that clang uses.  Also there's no way Rust could work properly even for building normal executables out of multiple source files (not just kernels) if the toolchain had the problem you're worried about.  I don't really know linker *scripts*, though, just how linkers work by default, so IDK if yours could be the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I figure it out. Thanks to the hints offered by [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes). The reason is that I compiled my rust code to an executable rather than a library. I should compile it into a library(a `.a` file) so the linker can calculate the offset of rip-relative addressing during link-time. If it's compiled into an executable then the offset is already calculated so the linker can't recalculate it and the problem I mentioned will arouse. Please forgive me that this is a silly mistake(how could you link an executable with other), I haven't look into such things seriously before.

Comment: I'm surprised any linker would even accept an executable as input instead of `.o` files (loose or in a `.a`).  But apparently you can `gcc -o hello hello.c` and then `gcc -nostartfiles -o foo hello` to make a broken executable.  Interesting.